# Deleting rows with 0 from a multidimentional array javascript

Tags: javascript

i have two sets of arrays that is joined to make it a two dimentional..what i like to do is to delete any rows that have 0 values in price after its joined then sort desending and display in an html table

```
    var desc = new Array();
    var desc = ["Water","Heating","Electric","Gas"];

    var price = new Array();
    var price=["824","325","0","245"];

    var sortdesc;
    var sortdesc = new Array (2);

    for (i = 0; i < desc . length; ++ i)
    {   
      for (var i=0; i < price.length; i++)
        {
                    sortdesc[i] = Array(desc[i], price[i]);
                    if (price[i] == 0 )  
                     {       
                     sortdesc.splice(i,1);

                  }  
              }
     }


    sortdesc.sort(function(a,b){ return b[1] - a[1]; });

    function sortedtable (array)
    {

        document . write("<table  border>");
        var row;
        for (row = 0; row < array . length; ++ row)
        {
        document . write(" <tr>");
        var col;
        for (col = 0; col < array [row].length; ++ col)
            document . write("  <td>" + array [row] [col] + "</td>");
        document . write(" </tr>");

        }

        document.write("</table>");
    }

    sortedtable(sortdesc);
```

the questions are i thought the .splice() will restructure the array what did i do wrong?
and is there a better way to do this

i saw other question but they all said use .splice() instead of delete.array[element] but the .splice is not working for me

please pardon my code beginner here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`splice` successfully removes the item from the array, yet in the next loop turn you are assigning to `sortdesc[i]` again so the the removed index will stay `undefined` - you created a sparse array.

Apart from that, you have a big problem with your nested loops which use the same count variable. It does not end up in an infinite loop at least since `price.length >= desc.length`, but the construct is highly questionable.

To solve you problems, just add new elements (and only if you really want to add them) to the end of the `sortdesc` array by using `push()`:

```
// no need to double initialize
var desc = ["Water","Heating","Electric","Gas"];
var price = ["824","325","0","245"];

// the Array constructor does not take dimensions. You just want an empty array here
var sortdesc = [];

// … to fill it with other arrays:
for (var i = 0, l = Math.min(desc.length, price.length); i < l; i++) {
    if (price[i] != 0) {
        sortdesc.push( [desc[i], price[i]] );
    }
}
```

Comment: i like Math.min(desc.length, price.length)..Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you shouldn't need to splice/delete from the array, just do a check beforehand and do not add items if the price is zero.

Another quick comment - from your data, it looks like both the desc and price arrays will have the same length. In this case, you can just use one for loop, no need to iterate through both.

Working code:

```
var desc = ["Water","Heating","Electric","Gas"];

var price = ["824","325","0","245"];

var sortdesc = [];

// Presuming both arrays with be the same length
for (i = 0; i < desc.length; ++ i) {
    if(price[i] !== "0") {
        sortdesc.push([desc[i], price[i]]);
    }
}

sortdesc.sort(function(a,b){ return b[1] - a[1]; });

function sortedtable (array)
{

    document . write("<table  border>");
    for (row = 0; row < array.length; ++ row)
    {
        document . write(" <tr>");
        for (col = 0; col < array[row].length; ++ col)
            document . write("  <td>" + array [row] [col] + "</td>");
        document . write(" </tr>");
    }

    document.write("</table>");
}

sortedtable(sortdesc);
```